# UIScrollView / UIView Zoom Problem

Tags: iphone, uiview, zooming

my application has a UIScrollView with a UIView as subview. Both are the same size. The scrollView contains a large image and the subview is a "overlay" view that holds markers that are set when the user taps at the large image (a map). It is basically a simple app that allows to set markers on certain locations on a map.

so far so good. Setting markers and scrolling the scrollView works (markers keep the position on the map). However, there is one problem left. When i zoom in/out, the markers (in the overlay view) are positioned incorrectly (the markers move to the upper left corner when i zoom in). I have already tried to transform the marker positions using the convertPoint() method but unfortunatelly without success.

My UIView Hierarchy looks like this:

```
[mapScrollView addSubview:mapImageView]; // mapScrollView obviously is the scrollview. it holds
                                         // an UIView with an image (map).

[mapScrollView addSubview:mapImageAnnotationView]; // UIView that holds annotations (markers)

[mapImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap]; // handle taps
[mapImageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
[mapImageView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];

[self addSubview:mapScrollView]; // self is the container UIView that holds the composition
```

Size/bound setup:

```
mapImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: mapImage]; // init with image file
mapScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(mapImageView.frame.size.width,mapImageView.frame.size.height);
mapScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;

mapImageAnnotationView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, mapImageViewWidth, mapImageViewWidth)];
```

can anybody point me into the right direction to fix this problem ?

thanks

Comment: thanks for formatting the code aBitObvious

Answer (score 4):

Which view are you returning in the delegate method viewForZoomingInScrollView?

You should put your map and your overlays inside the same superview, add the super view into the scrollview and then return that superview in the delegate method

Comment: I restructured my uiview hierarchy as you suggested and now it works! Thank you Pacu!

Comment: I'm glad I could Help! Please accept the answer so everyone else checking up your question knows about this. ;)